# Chrome not validating required fields

Tags: html, google-chrome, form-submit

I am using the required to show form fields that are required.  I heard this is a bug in chrome but wanted to know if there was a work around.  My code is posted below.

```
echo "<br><br><input class=button id=submitbutton type=submit value=\"".pcrtlang("Submit     Service Request")."\" onclick=\"this.disabled=true;this.value='".pcrtlang("Sending Request")."...'; this.form.submit();\">";
```

I believe it will work if you remove the onlick function but then you have an issue if a user double clicks the submit button it will submit twice.

I use a javascript to disable the submit button to prevent double submissions, and then javascript to make the form submit.

Comment: Try add \" for the attributes. <input class=\"button\" id=\"submission" type=\"submit\" required>. I just tried the required in all 3 versions of Chrome I have (Linux Mageia, MacOS 10.6 and Win7) and it worked. Im using this [page](http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_required) to test.

Comment: I didn't mean to type required in the code above because that is the submit button.  I added the \" for each attribute but it still submits without checking in chrome.  I use a javascript to disable the submit button to prevent double submissions, and then javascript to make the form submit, if that makes a difference to your answer.

Comment: A note here: html5 supports boolean attributes, meaning that you should specify `<input required>` instead of `<input required="required">`.

Comment: @AnthonyRusso: you can edit your questions if the specifics were incorrect.

Comment: Yes I was using just required.  I apologize for the confusion.  I edited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that onclick is being called everytime (even when its not going to submit by the browser).
You can fix by changing the onclick to onsubmit ([JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvmP3/))

```
 <input class="button" id="submitbutton" type="submit" value="Submit" onsubmit="this.disabled=true;this.value='Sending Request';">
```

Answer (score 0):

I would be tempted to bind to the `submit` event of the containing form, and use the concept from  [_.debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) to limit the repetition of submissions:

jQuery:

```
// prevent the user from submitting the form twice within a second
var DELAY = 1000;
var lastSubmit = null;

$("#form").submit(function(e) {
  if (lastSubmit === null || Date.now() - lastSubmit > DELAY)
    return true;
  // two ways to prevent the default action
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

Or staight JavaScript:

```
// prevent the user from submitting the form twice within a second
var DELAY = 1000;
var lastSubmit = null;

document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
  if (lastSubmit === null || Date.now() - lastSubmit > DELAY)
    return true;
  // two ways to prevent the default action
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
});
```

You can tune `DELAY` to meet your requirements, or handle the form submission failing to reset a disabled state.

If a requirement is to use attributes for the hooks, then:

```
echo "<form onsubmit=\"var stop = lastSubmit && Date.now() - lastSubmit <= 1000;stop && e.preventDefault();return !stop;\">";
```